# SQL Server Geometry .STBuffer() distance measurement units

Tags: sql, sql-server, distance, units-of-measurement, geography

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971293/sql-server-2008-geography-stbuffer-distance-measurement-units) examines geography::STBuffer.  Expanding on David Storfer's comment, geometry fields are treated differently and have an entirely different set of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stbuffer-geometry-data-type).  However, that documentation doesn't explore the issue of units in great detail.  Our information contains SHAPE data stored as a geometry field so I need to know what units is geometry::STBuffer using?

Comment: I always thought that the geometry type was more abstract - it's just about a two dimensional coordinate system. If we have two points at positions (1,4) and (5,2), you can ask what the distance between them is and get a number. But asking about what *units* that result is in is meaningless since that entirely depends on what units *you* were thinking about when you said a point was at (1,4) rather than sating it was at (1000, 4000)

Comment: I did have a read of the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-types-overview#differences) regarding the spatial data types so I understand what you are saying about the result but the documentation states that "measurements of distances and areas are given in the same unit of measurement as coordinates" and so, there is a unit of measurement.  When a user asks me how close does something need to be before you alert me, I cannot reply 500 units, so you see my dilemma - I must know what units are being used.

Comment: Units of measure are sometimes used for conversion to the same unit (advanced algebra from what I can recall).  With Geometry fields, units are of no consequence because all values are assumed to be the same unit so, no conversion is required.  The answer to my question does appear to be that I just need to look at the units of the original datasets and to determine that will most likely depend on the type of spatial datasets that is being.

Answer (score 2):

This [discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d698ca09-b683-45d2-8998-6f335c9c1fa7/projected-coordinate-system-support?forum=sqlspatial) states "coordinate systems in sys.spatial_reference_systems are for the geography type" so despite looking at this in detail, it appeared that this information was not relevant to this question.  After some further investigation, I resorted to using STDistance and manually examining a map to confirm that for our information at least, geometry::STBuffer (and geometry::STDistance) the values being used correspond with meters being used as the distance of measure.  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971293/sql-server-2008-geography-stbuffer-distance-measurement-units) suggests that the return value from STDistance is in degrees but that was not the behaviour that I observed.  Following the [GIS SO link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/stdistance-unit-in-sql-server-2008) provided on that page and the subsequent [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e04f0afd-a266-4847-bc21-5e42669e5eb5/stdistance-semantics?forum=sqlspatial), where it was once again stated that "The SRIDs listed in sys.spatial_reference_systems refer to the geography type only" and, that "For the geometry type, the linear units returned by methods such as Distance, Length, and Area are always in the unit coordinates of the points", I concluded that the answer to this question actually depends on what unit was used to create the dataset.

P.S.  Of course, I now wanted to know how to determine the unit of my information.  This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037354/sql-server-units-question) examines units in general and the accepted answer ran along the lines of *if your data columns were created with an SRID of 0, then the system is defined to be unit-less and you would need some metadata about the data model to figure out the units*. If they were defined with a real SRID, then you can query sys.spatial_reference_systems.  So it seems I had to return to where I started, looking at sys.spatial_reference_systems.  Another [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d698ca09-b683-45d2-8998-6f335c9c1fa7/projected-coordinate-system-support?forum=sqlspatial) appears to support the notion that spatial_reference_systems is relevant when discussing geometry fields.

This [GIS SO post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19902/how-i-get-srid-from-geometry-field) explains how to determine which SRID is actually being used by your data - (select distinct SP_GEOMETRY.STSrid from dbo.MYTABLE).  That can then be matched against the information in sys.spatial_reference_systems although, it takes a bit more work to determine which record in sys.spatial_reference_systems is a match, e.g. when using our data select distinct SP_GEOMETRY.STSrid from dbo.MYTABLE returned 28355 but that value doesn't appear in sys.spatial_reference_systems - according to http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/gda94-mga-zone-55/html/ that value is actually an identifier for the projection.  Looking through the contents returned by spatialreference.org, the authority details (AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]) look like they provide the appropriate SRID to match a record in sys.spatial_reference_systems.  In our case, the unit_of_measure is listed as metre.

P.P.S.  Interested to hear thoughts before deciding if I post comments in some of the references above.